# Magento 2: Walk through collection and delete

Tags: magento2, database, collection

I was wondering if there was a way of **walking through a collection on Magento 2 and deleting entries from the databas**e.

In Magento 1, this could be done by doing something like the following:

```
Mage::getModel('foo/bar')->getCollection()
                    ->addFilter('baz', $filter)
                    ->walk('delete')
```

Is there a way of achieving something similar in Magento 2?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's the same method in M2 you can do

```
$collection->walk('delete');
```

A few examples from native Magento 2 files:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/CronJob/CleanExpiredOrders.php#L61
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Adminhtml/Problem/Grid.php#L43

Comment: Really appreciate!

Answer (score 8):

I could easily be wrong, but I think it depends on the entity with which you are working. Take a couple references from the core, e.g.:

`\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection::delete()`

```
public function delete()
{
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $key => $item) {
        $this->getEntity()->delete($item);
        unset($this->_items[$key]);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

`\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\MassDelete::massAction()`:

```
protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
{
    $customersDeleted = 0;
    foreach ($collection->getAllIds() as $customerId) {
        $this->customerRepository->deleteById($customerId);
        $customersDeleted++;
    }
    //snip...
}
```

`\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete::execute()`

```
public function execute()
{
    $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
    $productDeleted = 0;
    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {
        $product->delete();
        $productDeleted++;
    }
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
        __('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $productDeleted)
    );

    return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT)->setPath('catalog/*/index');
}
```

It comes down to whether there is a service layer setup for the entity.

Comment: It sounds about right, my answer was specific to the OP case as it seems like he/she used to do that with a custom entity back in M1

Comment: Yep, mine evidently waited hours to post. Most likely because I forgot all about it and never actually clicked "post"