# How to delete the content of a table

Tags: magento2, database, model

I'm able to fetch the single items, or the whole tables via the `$modelFactory->create()->load(ID)` or `$modelFactory->create()->getCollection()`

Using the $modelFactory, how can I delete all the data fetched?

---- UPDATE ----

The code I'm using at the moment is the following one. I guess it's running a query per item, instead of doing one query for all the items, so I'm looking for a way to do it in one single shot.

```
$cleanup = $this->myModelFactory->create()->getCollection();
foreach($cleanup as $item) {
   $item->delete();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it now?

Comment: @DanielBlack is not wrong it's more something about performance.
I expect that an SQL query will be run at each foreach recursion. So if for example `$cleanup` has 50 items, the foreach loop will generate 50 SQL delete query instead of one with all the items to delete.

Comment: Why not run a direct SQL query?

Comment: @acf it should be part of a process, so I'd like to use the magneto way as much as possible

Comment: @LuigiT. You can still use SQL using the Resource Connection class and make it part of a process.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Adminhtml/Problem/Grid.php#L43

```
$cleanup = $this->myModelFactory->create()->getCollection();
$cleanup->walk('delete');
```

This was already answered on: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/118128/36271